# Using try statements when sorting through frames

Tags: python, selenium

So I have multiple dynamic frames that have names that change depending on what elements are being clicked. I've tried using `try` statements like this:

```py
try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-1']/iframe"))
except:
       try:
         driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-4']/iframe"))
       except:
            try:
                driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-7']/iframe"))
            except:
                   print("Failed to find a frame")
```

However as soon as I pass over the first frame it will never find the second frame (in this case id-4).

I've also tried finding frames by using src:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[src*="text-within-frame"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```

What am I do wrong/what should I be doing differently?

EDIT:

Ok so when I run through the program it will always get to the first frame, access and scrape all the data I need, and then fail once it tries to move on to the next frame area to scrape. I think the issue is that once Frame 1 exists it always finds Frame 1 even if it is no longer there and the new data I need is on Frame 2 (id-4 in my case). Is there a way where I can have my code disregard Frame 1 once it is used?

Here is an explanation of what I need in a non-code accurate way to hopefully help explain a bit better.:

```py
Switch to Frame 1

if Frame 1 already used:
     Switch to Frame 2
          if Frame 2 already used:
             Switch to Frame 3
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What you are doing now essentially always displays the first frame, then second if the first fails, then third if the second fails. If you want to display a frame base on the elements, you should do it in an if-elseif clause.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, I have updated my question to reflect the problem I discovered.

Comment: You can't predict which frame is correct ? Or the order of activation ?

Comment: The frames are always created in the order of: Frame 1, Frame 2, Frame 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
try:
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-7']/iframe"))
    except: 
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-4']/iframe"))
        except:
            try:
                driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-1']/iframe"))
            except:
                print("Couldn't find frame")
```

I needed to reverse the order in which my program searched for frames since the original frame, ui-id-1, was always available after being used the first time. So when I would try to move to the next frame I needed it would always find ui-id-1 and then return an exception. Figured I should post in case anyone ever runs across a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would running it in a loop work?

```
xpath = ["//*[@id='ui-id-1']/iframe", "//*[@id='ui-id-4']/iframe", "//*[@id='ui-id-7']/iframe"]
for i in xpath:
    try:
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath(i)
    except:
        print("failed to find a frame")
```

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the issue I discovered after running your code. I basically need my code to disregard searching for a frame once its been used since it is then always available.

Comment: after rereading your updated question I am still unclear. A loop will always run every frame ? if xpath 1 is run and completed in the next iteration of the loop it will go to xpath 2 etc. The logic could be inside the  `try:' block?   sorry

Comment: Yeah this is a confusing question, so I think I got it to work by actually reversing my original try statement. Instead of searching like this: 1, 3, 7 it now searches and goes 7, 3, 1 so it will never go over a frame that has been used before.